# Regex preg_match issue with commas

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is my code to pre_match when an amount looks like this: $ 99.00 and it works

```
if (preg_match_all('/[$]\s\d+(\.\d+)?/', $tout, $matches))
{ $tot2 = $matches[0];
$tot2 = preg_replace("/\\\$/", '', $tot2);}
```

I need to do the same thing for a amount that looks like this (with a comma): $ 99,00

Thank you for your help (changing dot for comma do not help, there is an "escape" thing I do not understand...

Idealy I need to preg_match any number that looks like an amount with dot or commas and with or without dollar sign before or after (I know, it's a lot to ask :) since on the result form I want to scan there  are phone and street numbers...

UPDATE (For some reason I cannot comment on replies) : To test properly, I need to preg_replace the comma by a dot (since we are dealings with sums, I don't think calculations can be done on numbers with commas in it).

So to clarify my question, I should say : I need to transform, let's say "$ 200,24" to "200.24". (could be amounts bettween 0.10 to 1000.99) :

```
    $tot2 = preg_replace("/\\\$/", '', $tot2);}
```

(this code just deals with the $ (it works), I need adaptation to deal also with the change of (,) for (.))

Answer (score 2):

No, using `,` in place of `\.` works perfectly fine.

It's just that your input does not contain a space between dollar sign and amount `$ 99,00` like your `.`-using source did.

Make the `\s` optional.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str='$ 200,24';
echo str_replace(array('$',',',' '), array('','.',''), $str);
```

**output:**

```
200.24
```

Answer (score -1):

replace the . character with a character class [,.] which includes both a dot(.) and comma(,)

```
'/[$]\s\d+([.,]\d+)?/'
```

edit: comment is correct, regex fixed.

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot in a character class.